# Fix Label Exogenous Variables in summary_col with python statsmodels

Tags: python, pandas, regression, statsmodels

I want to produce regression tables like those yielded by summary_col (standard journal tables) but with custom explanatory variable labels.

Is there a way to change the row names saved in the model params attribute?

As of now I rename variables the closest I can to what I intend, but there ought to be a better way to do this.

Comment: `summary_col` stores the results in a pandas DataFrame, attached in `tables` attribute. It should be possible to reindex it with new variable names. (I don't know the details.)

Comment: That's not correct. At least in the version I have, summary_col.tables is a list.

Comment: Still, it is possible to use that idea:
reg = smf.ols(formula = "y~x1+x2+x3 ").fit()
def rename_vars(vname):
    to_ret = vname
    if vname == 'original_vname':
        to_ret = 'new_vname'
    return to_ret
    
def rename_ols(reg):
    for i in range(len(reg)):
        reg[i] = rename_vars(reg[i])
Then, just do: 
rename_ols(reg.model.exog_names)
And there it is.
I can't post this as an answer as I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have done

```
reg = smf.ols(formula = "y~x1+x2+x3").fit()
```

I suggest (1) to have a dictionary where you hold all the relabeling:
dic = {original_vname: new_name}
a (2) a pair of useful functions:

```
def rename_vars(vname): 
    to_ret = vname
    for orig_vname in list(dic.keys()):
        if vname == 'original_vname':
            to_ret = dic['original_vname'] 
    return to_ret
```

and

```
def rename_ols(reg): 
    for i in range(len(reg)): 
        reg[i] = rename_vars(reg[i])
```

Then, just do:

```
rename_ols(reg.model.exog_names)
```

And that's it. Once you call summary_col, the variables will show up with the new labels.